# Jquery Ajax: Data is undefined when accessing the returned data of json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using an MVC approach here. In my javascript code, under the success function.. when I use the **console.log(data.msg)** code, my expected result comes up.

But when I use the **$('#res').text("".data.msg)** .. the output is **TypeError: "".data is undefined** from the console..

And if  I use **$('#res').text(data.msg)**... There is no output in the console..

I expect the result to show in the text field having the id of res.

Here is the html code

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="uname">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">

    <input type="text" id="res">
</form>
```

Here is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'ajax/checkLogin',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {
            uname : $('#uname').val(),
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#res').text("".data.msg);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("There was an error");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

And here is the method code of the controller named Ajax

```
public function checkLogin()
{
    $return['error'] = false;

    while (true) {
        if (empty($_POST['uname'])) {
            $return['error'] = true;
            $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you username.';
            break;
        }

        if ($_POST['uname'] == "tin") {
            $return['msg'] = 'successful';
            break;
        }else{
            $return['error'] = true;
            $return['msg'] = 'Wrong username:'.$_POST['uname'];
            break;
        }
        break;
    }

    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

Comment: so what give you `console.log(data);` ???

Comment: `And if I use $('#res').text(data.msg)... There is no output in the console..` How this code will output the data in the console..?

Comment: @A.Wolff [object Object]

Comment: Don't tell me you are debugging it using IE?!

Comment: @Katherine For wolf: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: @A.Wolff i debug it in mozilla firefox... here is the output from the code given by Raja... "{"error":true,"msg":"Wrong username:asd"}" ... the msg is the one that i want to output in a text field

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `dot` before `data`, you probably do not need empty string concatenation with data.

```
$('#res').text(data.msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#res').text("".data.msg);
```

change this to

```
$('#res').text(data.msg);
```

It is quite clear from the error. TypeError: "".data is undefined. Since string doesn't have a property `data`

Comment: thanks.. but there is no output when i tried the $('#res').text(data.msg);

Comment: Try to log data and make sure the ajax call is success full. Or show us the expected JSON response

Comment: yes i tried to log it.. the ajax call was successful. But the result message doesn't show in the textfield

Comment: @Katherine ok `#res` is an input, not a DIV, so use `.val()` not `.text()`. I'm quite sure i saw it as DIV but cannot see any edit for question, strange...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to concatenate string in javascript with the PHP operator.
To concatenate two strings, you have to use the + operator not the . operator

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted empty string then concate it by `+` not by `.`

```
$('#res').text(""+data.msg);
```